# Wso2 apim custom metrics

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We are planning to deploy apim and charge developers by custom metric(the number of characters in one of the properties of the request body). Is it possible to do this without modifying apim sources ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the following.

1. Add a global or API level custom mediation policy - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/api-gateway/message-mediation/changing-the-default-mediation-flow-of-api-requests/#creating-per-api-mediation-policies

You can write a class mediator to read the request body and do any calculation. Then publish data to another service in an asynchronous way.

2. You can write a handler to do the same - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/extending-api-manager/extending-gateway/writing-custom-handlers/#introducing-handlers